# Sql procedure variables

Tags: sql, variables, stored-procedures

I have this sql procedure statement, but it fails because of the variables:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE iskanje(@iskani_niz)
BEGIN
SELECT A.ime, A.opis, B.kategorija
FROM file as A, cathegory as B
WHERE A.ime LIKE '%'+@iskani_niz+'%' 
OR A.opis LIKE '%'+@iskani_niz+'%' 
OR B.kategorija LIKE '%'+@iskani_niz+'%';
END
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Well, you need to give your parameter **a datatype!** - e.g. `iskanje(@iskani_niz INT)` or  `iskanje(@iskani_niz VARCHAR(50))` or whatever it is your parameter really is!

Comment: Also, I don't see a joining `WHERE` clause. What columns does `file` and `cathegory` join on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im so sorry for that late answer... What I found is there are differend syntaxes for procedures in sql and mysql... So the real syntax should be like this:

```
set delimiter //

create procedure iskanje(in naziv varchar(10))

BEGIN
    SELECT A.ime, A.opis, B.kategorija
    FROM file as A, cathegory as B
    WHERE A.ime LIKE concat('%',naziv,'%')
       OR A.opis LIKE concat('%',naziv,'%')
       OR B.kategorija LIKE concat('%',naziv,'%');
END//

set delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead to declare your parameter to the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE iskanje
    @iskani_niz nvarchar(max)
AS BEGIN

SELECT A.ime, A.opis, B.kategorija
FROM file as A, cathegory as B
WHERE A.ime LIKE '%'+@iskani_niz+'%' 
   OR A.opis LIKE '%'+@iskani_niz+'%' 
   OR B.kategorija LIKE '%'+@iskani_niz+'%';

END
```

Note that you should specify a better type than `nvarchar(max)`, which I assumed based on your usage in the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: I get this error:
#1064 - You have an error in your ... for the right syntax to use near 'declare (A)iskalni_niz varchar(10) set (A)iskalni_niz = 'ad' SELECT A.ime, A.opi' at line 1